# Reading Dfs0 file from 2011

Tags: mikeio

I work at a company that had some work done at DHI in 2011.
We have chosen to further analyse some of the data, but we only have it in Dfs0 format.
I have installed the mikeio package, and written:

```
import mikeio
ds = mikeio.Dfs0("0019log1.dfs0")
```

but i get an attributeError:
`AttributeError: 'DfsEqTimeAxis' object has no attribute 'StartDateTime'`

I do not know if this is because the files were made so long ago, or if the person who made them made a mistake. I have not worked with Dfs0 files before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files with relative time axis are not very common, and was not possible to read with mikeio until recently.

Now it should be fine, as long as you are fine with that the time is defined relative to 1970-01-01 00:00.

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 06:50:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mikeio import Dfs0
>>> dfs0 = Dfs0("eq_relative.dfs0")
>>> dfs0
Dfs0
Timeaxis: TimeAxisType.EquidistantRelative
Items:
  0:  Item 1  (undefined)
  1:  Item 2  (undefined)
  2:  Item 3  (undefined)
  3:  Item 4  (undefined)
  4:  Item 5  (undefined)
>>> ds = dfs0.read()
>>> ds

Dimensions: (504,)
Time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 - 1970-01-01 00:00:56.236909
Items:
  0:  Item 1  (undefined)
  1:  Item 2  (undefined)
  2:  Item 3  (undefined)
  3:  Item 4  (undefined)
  4:  Item 5  (undefined)
>>> ds["Item 1"][0:10
... ]
array([-0.0068621 , -0.01174611, -0.0068621 , -0.0019781 ,  0.00290591,
        0.00290591,  0.00290591,  0.00290591, -0.0019781 , -0.0068621 ])
>>> ds.time[0:10]
DatetimeIndex([       '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.111803',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.223606', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.335409',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.447212', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.559015',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.670818', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.782621',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.894424', '1970-01-01 00:00:01.006227'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='111803U')
```